# Core Animation: Mask a CAShapeLayer with a CAGradientLayer masked with a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, core-animation, quartz-core, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

This is mainly about 'advanced' masking in core animation using CAGradientLayer and CAShapeLayer.

Basically, I have a nice complicated shape made out of a CGPath displayed using a CAShapeLayer *s1*. I need to dim a segment of the shape.
So, I create a CAGradientLayer *g1* with a gradient in the direction of my segment, all good. 
Then, I create another CAShapeLayer *s2* well shaping the segment I want to dim.

I mask the CAGradientLayer *g1* using the CAShapeLayer *s2* (g1.mask = s2). 
If I add *g1* as a sublayer, it is perfect.

However, I need to use the masked CAGradientLayer *g1* to mask *s1*. 
When I do s1.mask = *g1*; *s1* is masked with the normal version of *g1*, not the version masked with *s2*.

So basically, I am doing or at least trying to do: 
CAGradientLayer1.mask =  CAShapeLayer1;
CAShapeLayer1.mask = CAGradientLayer1;

But it is currently just outputting!
CAShapeLayer1.mask = CAGradientLayer1;

Hope this helps. If not clear enough, I'll post some images.

Cheers.